# Não foi possível localizar o Provedor de Dados .Net Framework solicitado. Sql Server + Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, razor

Estou tendo problema ao conectar com o meu banco local. Esta é a minha *View*, onde tento conectar o banco utilizando Razor:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutOuvinte.cshtml";

    var db = Database.Open("Entities");
    var selectQuery = "select * from musica";
    var grid = new WebGrid(db.Query(selectQuery));

}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle:"table table-hover table-bordered",
headerStyle: null,
alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("au_Nome","Nome"),
    grid.Column("au_nomeArtista","NomeArtista")
    )
   ) 
</div>
```

Porém quando eu entro nessa *View*, o seguinte erro é mostrado:

> Não foi possível localizar o Provedor de Dados .Net Framework
>   solicitado. Talvez ele não esteja instalado.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentException: Não foi possível
>   localizar o Provedor de Dados .Net Framework solicitado. Talvez ele
>   não esteja instalado.

Pelo o que eu percebi, eu tenho que adicionar um provider no `web.config`, mas não acho onde pegar isso. Este é o meu `web.config`. Coloquei no Pastebin para melhor visualização do tópico.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.mdf;initial catalog=aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <machineKey validationKey="E80134C01840C86CEB5E302517525ADE46900E9763E9EC62B55635521F65F83FB1CABD33244D1CA49BBC602C792CC480C5EEB7F348CEAC750B5DBBA0661A8377" decryptionKey="F2EE1666A4F0116064804A5860FBE4774B03311E6DC0326CE71102F19AEF27C0" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YfG7LGTa)

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta seu arquivo `Web.config`?

Comment: Ele está no link do pastebin na pergunta, obrigado

Comment: Você instalou alguma versão do SQL Server Express juntamente com seu Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Tem algo muito esquisito nesta entrada:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.mdf;initial catalog=aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Não faço ideia de onde você montou isto, mas tem uma grande chance de estar errado, até porque nunca ouvi falar de um *provider* chamado `System.Data.EntityClient`. Troque para:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso ta acontecendo porque você não ta declarando explicitamente o provedor que você ta usando, ou seja, seu banco de dados.

Então pra resolver isso,tente o seguinte:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

## Explicando aqui:

- No seu web.config navegue até a tag:
  `<entityFramework>`
- Copie e cole toda a tag
- Dê build no seu projeto pra fazer todas as alterações

Espero ter ajudado !

OBS: Só de lembrete, coloque a referência ao SQL Server ou ao seu banco de preferência. Coloquei a resposta já supondo que você tem essas referências em seu projeto.