# Provedor de dados .net framework solicitado. talvez ele não esteja instalado

Tags: entity-framework

Eu uso entity framework 5 em um projeto MVC.
Quando estava com o framework 4.0 instalado no Pc ele funcionava perfeitamente.
Agora que instalei o . Net framework 4.5 SDK e o framework 4.6 ao rodar a aplicação aparece a mensagem abaixo:

não foi possível localizar o provedor de dados .net framework solicitado. talvez ele não esteja instalado.

Sabem o que posso fazer para resolver?

Comment: Chegou a desinstalar a Framework 4.0? Também pode verificar nessa pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54621/n%C3%A3o-foi-poss%C3%ADvel-localizar-o-provedor-de-dados-net-framework-solicitado-sql-se?rq=1

Comment: Peguei os arquivos machine.config e web.config na pasta do framework em uma máquina que a aplicação estava rodando, fiz o Merge com os arquivos da minha máquina e a aplicação funcionou.